# How to make VoiceOver acknowledge link with SVG inside it?

Tags: ios, svg, anchor, accessibility, voiceover

I have an anchor with an svg inside of it. Using Voiceover on iPhone, I cannot get the link to have focus by tapping on it. If I replace the `<img>` tag, with an inline `<svg>` tag, I can. It also works fine on OSX.

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="image/btn-arrow-left.svg" alt="Logo"/></a>
```

I would prefer not to have an inline svg here. This seems like a bug to me. But is there some way to make VoiceOver acknowledge this link?

Comment: Looks like a bug, can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am not sure of somewhere I can hotlink an svg from... but it would basically be exactly as above but with a working SVG. I've checked a few svgs and a few different contexts and it seems to happen in all situations. Feel like it's probably a bug as well, but I'm curious about any way of tricking it into working or why it might be happening

Comment: Which browser and operating system are you using?

Comment: @unobf safari for iOS8

Comment: Were you able to solve this, @damon.

Comment: Nope :( Set it as inline and just went with it. iOS 8.3 solved a number of really bizarre accessibility issues (like aria-hidden reporting the opposite of how it was set) but this one is just how it "works" it seems. Are you having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue on iOS 10.1.1, where in cases like this, VoiceOver would acknowledge the link, but would not read the image's `alt` text:

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="image.svg" alt="Logo"></a>
```

As a related issue, VoiceOver would not acknowledge an `<img>` with an svg as its `src`, and thus would not read its `alt` text.

---

I was able to work around this by adding a redundant `role="img"` to the `<img>`:

```
<img src="image.svg" alt="Logo" role="img">
```

---

Judging from these bug report threads, this seems to happen only when the svg has no accessible contents.

- [Bug 145263 – AX:  elements with an SVG src are ignored by VO despite valid alt attribute](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145263)
- [Bug 160705 – AX: @alt and bounds ignored when using img[src] points to an inaccessible SVG](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160705)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the SVG accessible in best practice, unfortunately I believe you would have to use the `<svg>` tag.  There are some examples here:  [Tips for Creating Accessible SVG](http://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/).  I don't think this is a bug, I think it is by design.

However, there may be ways to go with what you are wanting.  If you want to remain with the existing code, you may have to put in a span tag with a `sr-only` class on it.

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="image/btn-arrow-left.svg" alt="To the Left" title="To the Left" aria-labelledby="linkText" /><span class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" id="linkText">To the Left</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
.sr-only-focusable:active,
.sr-only-focusable:focus {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  clip: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps your cause.

Comment: I would hope it's not by design. Using svg in an image tag is for sure normal and [pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img).  I'm not sure the sr-only approach is fully workable bc it's also for limited sight users who are tapping the screen.

Comment: @Damon its just that using the svg tag allows for more aria attributes and roles, as well as child nodes, which assistive technology can take advantage of.

Comment: totally understand that. But I don't think inlining should be a requirement for them to function. Managing inline svgs can be a bit of a challenge